# How to get all files and folders recursively using GetMetadata activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to delete many folders with an exempt list which has a list of folders and files that I should not delete. So I tried `delete activity` and tried to use `if` function of `Add dynamic content` to check whether the file or folder name is the same of the specified ones. But I do not have what should be the parameters @if(). In other words, to use these functions, how do we get the file name or folder name?

Comment: what is type of your dataset? blob, data lake gen 2 or else?

Comment: it is blob storage

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to get all files and folders by using GetMetadata activity.

As workarounds, you can try these ways:

1.create a Delete activity and select List of files option. Then create a file filled with those path of files and folders need to be deleted.(relative path to the path configured in the dataset).
[image]

2.using blob SDK to do this thing.